# Object doesn't support property or method 'submit' in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, submit

I'm using jquery.fileupload.js and jquery 1.7.2.

```
<input class="file_upload_start" type="file" name="files[]" original-title="" multiple="multiple">
```

My file.js: http://www.kcloud.vn/apps/files/js/files.js

```
$(function () {
    $('.file_upload_start').fileupload({
        dropZone:$('#content'), // restrict dropZone to content div
        add:function (e, data) {
            var files = data.files;
            var totalSize = 0;


data.submit().success(function (data, status) {
    response = jQuery.parseJSON(data[0].body.innerText);
    if (response[0] != undefined && response[0].status == 'success') {
        var file = response[0];
        delete uploadingFiles[file.name];
        $('tr').filterAttr('data-file', file.name).data('mime', file.mime);
        var size = $('tr').filterAttr('data-file', file.name).find('td.filesize').text();
        if (size == t('files', 'Pending')) {
            $('tr').filterAttr('data-file', file.name).find('td.filesize').text(file.size);
        }
        FileList.loadingDone(file.name);
    }
```

When I run it, I get the error:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'submit'
>   files.js, line 387 character 37

How do fix it?

Comment: where is data defined? the stuff after it isn't important.

Comment: $(function () {

        $('.file_upload_start').fileupload({

            dropZone:$('#content'), // restrict dropZone to content div
            add:function (e, data) {
                var files = data.files;
                var totalSize = 0;

Comment: http://www.kcloud.vn/apps/files/js/files.js

Comment: afaik, you can't trigger `.submit` on anything but `form` elements, and data doesn't seem to be one.

Comment: @shiftoff per the documentation: *"The upload starts when the submit method is invoked on the data parameter."* @sepdau: Confirm that `.file_upload_start` is what it is supposed to be. Otherwise, raise this issue with the developer. Are you using the latest version of the plugin?

Comment: I use * jQuery File Upload Plugin 5.9 is that ok?

Comment: <input class="file_upload_start" type="file" name="files[]" original-title="" multiple="multiple">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is an excerpt from http://www.kcloud.vn/apps/files/js/files.js up to Line 387. The code comments contain the explanation.

```
$(function () {
    $('.file_upload_start').fileupload({
        dropZone: $('#content'), // restrict dropZone to content div
        add: function (e, data) {
            //data.submit() should definitely exist in this scope.
            //...stuff...
            $.ajax({
                url: '/?app=files&getfile=ajax%2Fupload.php',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    //which "data" is scoped here? "add" (parent) or "success" (local)?
                    //IE is picking local scope, not parent, which is causing your error.
                    //Rename the parameter variable to something else.
                    if (data.data.message == "DAT") {
                        //...stuff...
                    } else {
                        if (files) {
                            //...stuff...
                        }
                        if (totalSize > $('#max_upload').val()) {
                            //...stuff...
                        } else {
                            if ($.support.xhrFileUpload) {
                                //...stuff...
                            } else { //"data" below in "success" scope does not have a "submit" method, hence your error.
                                data.submit().success(function (data, status) { // <-- Line 387
                                    //Yet another parameter variable named "data".
                                    //This is asking for more trouble, rename this one too,
                                    //or define your functions elsewhere and reference them here.
                                    //...stuff...
                                });
                            }
//...stuff...
```